# How to derive gradient of cross product with inner product combined?

Tags: vector-analysis

I encoutered following problem when deriving some dynamics equation.
Since lack of my background of vector calculus, I am having hard time derivng following equation.

$\nabla_{\vec{x}} \left( (\vec{x}\times \vec{y})^{T} (\vec{x} \times \vec{y}) \right) $

Anyone could help me out?

Comment: You can first use that for a vector field $u$: $\nabla_x \langle u(x),u(x)\rangle = 2\langle \nabla_x u(x), u(x)\rangle$ and then calculate the inner derivative. Using the Levi-Civita tensor for the cross product might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to calculate first the total derivative of $$f(x)=\langle x\times y,x\times y\rangle$$
at $p$ using the product rule:
$$D_pf(x)=2\langle x\times y,p\times y\rangle.$$
The using Lagrange we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}D_pf(x)&=\langle x,p\rangle\langle y,y\rangle -\langle y,p\rangle\langle x,y\rangle\\
&=\langle x\langle y,y\rangle,p\rangle-\langle y\langle  x,y\rangle,p\rangle\\
&=\langle x\langle y,y\rangle-y\langle x,y\rangle,p\rangle
\end{align}$$
Hence finally
$$\nabla f(x)=2(x\langle y,y\rangle-y\langle x,y\rangle)$$
which equals
$$2y\times(x\times y)$$
using the Graßmann-identity.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to derive it.